# Window always stay on top on Catalina?

Tags: catalina, window-manager

With Catalina, is there an easy solution to have a window (not just a browser window) always on top of other windows?

This is an example (Mutify) of a window that I always want to show on top:

[image]

Comment: Not easy, no.  You'd probably need some third-party software. What window do you want on top, and why?

Comment: A small window (Mutify) that shows if my microphone is muted or not.

Comment: Small? ;-) I'd ask the developers to include a menulet that shows the status, or add a preference to float the window.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the paid app [Fenetre](https://apps.apple.com/app/fen%C3%AAtre/id1286743037)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I haven't found a way to make the Mutify window stay on top using Fenetre.